# Active Passive Voice

Tags: passive-voice

What is the passive voice of the following sentence?

> The thief climbed over the wall without being seen.

Will it be

> The wall was climbed over by the thief without being seen.

or

> Without being seen, the thief climbed over the wall.

Comment: **without being seen** modifies the thief as he climbs; take him or her out of the picture and that phrase becomes meaningless. Your final sentence is simply an inversion of phrase order not a passive construction.

Comment: Not passive in respect to **climb**, that is.

Answer (score 2):

The thief climbed over the wall without being seen. <sup>active</sup>

The wall was climbed over by the thief without *him* being seen. <sup>passive</sup>

The chef removed his toque without saying a word. <sup>active</sup>

His toque was removed by the chef without his|him saying a word. <sup>passive</sup>